Finding the conditions that $a,b,c$ should satisfy s.t. $f^{(2)}(x_{0})\approx0$, where $f(x)=ax^{4}+bx^{3}-c$ and $a,b,c$ are all positive.
Recently, I encountered a problem related to finding the roots of an equation, which has troubled me for quite some time. The problem can be described as follows:
Given that $a,b,c$ are all arbitrary positive real numbers, how can I determine the value of the second derivative function at the the root of its first derivative function?
The function is of the form $f(x) = ax^{4} + bx^{3} - cx$, and its first derivative is:
$f'(x) = 4ax^{3} + 3bx^{2} - c$
Since $c$ is greater than $0$ and the above derivative is increasing and negative at $x=0$, this equation has only one positive root. Let's assume this positive root is $x_{0}$.
I want to obtain a result where $f^{(2)}(x_{0})$ is relatively small. What conditions should $a,b$ and $c$ satisfy to achieve this result?
Mathematica tells me that:

However, I am puzzled by the appearance of exponential functions in the final result. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or clarification from the experts. Moreover, the provided result does not help me identify the conditions that $a,b,c$ should meet in order to make $f^{(2)}(x_{0})\approx 0$.
Thank you to all the experts for your guidance!
Greatly appreciated!

Try solving the depressed cube $f'(x)$ and find $x_0$. Plug that in $f''(x)$ and this should help.

I will try your advice. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

May do it backward

Assuming $x_0 \not \approx 0$

\begin{align}
  f''(x) &= 6x(2ax+b) \\
  x_0 &\approx -\frac{b}{2a} \\
  0 &\approx
  4a\left( -\frac{b}{2a} \right)^3+
  3b\left( -\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2-c \\
  c &\approx \frac{b^3}{4a^2}
\end{align}
Further points to be noticed

For small $\delta$, $\epsilon$

\begin{align}
  c &= \frac{b^3}{4a^2}+\delta \\
  x_0 &= -\frac{b}{2a}+\epsilon \\
    f'(x) &= 4a
  \left( x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2
  \left( x-\frac{b}{4a} \right)-\delta \\
  f'(x_0) &= 4a
  \epsilon^2
  \left( \epsilon-\frac{3b}{4a} \right)-\delta \\
  \delta &= -3b\epsilon^2+4a\epsilon^3 \\
  \epsilon & \approx \pm \sqrt{-\frac{\delta}{3b}}
\end{align}

For real solution
$$\delta<0 \implies c\lesssim \frac{b^3}{4a^2}$$


Thanks a lot for your answer!

A little question is that: maybe $f'(x_{0})$ is not approximates $0$ since $f'(x)$ is a increasing function with respect to $x$?

Don't forget $x_0$ is negative and also is near the inflexion point where $f''=0$.
